# Get Wrong Result - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to construct a program that will tell me the product of the 13 adjacent numbers with the highest product. However, it keeps giving me the wrong answer. What is wrong with this code?

```
import java.lang.Character; 

public class ProjectEuler8 { public static void main(String[] args) { 

  String num = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"+
"9698352031277450632623957831801698480186947885184385861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"+
"1254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"+
"6222989342338030813533627661428280644448664523874930358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"+
"7017242712188399879790879227492190169972088809377665727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"+
"5258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"+
"8397224137565705605749026140797296865241453510047482166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"+
"1642717147992444292823086346567481391912316282458617866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"+
"2421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"+
"8458015616609791913387549920052406368991256071760605886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"+
"71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

  int NUM_LENGTH = num.length(); 

  char[] number = new char[NUM_LENGTH];

  for (int i=0; i<NUM_LENGTH; i++) { number[i] = num.charAt(i); }

  int mult=0; 
  int highest=0; 

  for (int j=0; j<=987; j++) {
  int a = number[j]; a=Character.getNumericValue(a); 
  int b = number[j+1]; b=Character.getNumericValue(b); 
  int c = number[j+2]; c=Character.getNumericValue(c); 
  int d = number[j+3]; d=Character.getNumericValue(d);   


  int e = number[j+4]; e=Character.getNumericValue(e); 
  int f = number[j+5]; f=Character.getNumericValue(f); 
  int g = number[j+6]; g=Character.getNumericValue(g); 
  int h = number[j+7]; h=Character.getNumericValue(h); 
  int i = number[j+8]; i=Character.getNumericValue(i); 
  int k = number[j+9]; k=Character.getNumericValue(k);
  int l = number[j+10]; l=Character.getNumericValue(l);
  int m = number[j+11]; m=Character.getNumericValue(m);
  int n = number[j+12]; n=Character.getNumericValue(n);

  mult = a*b*c*d*e*f*g*h*i*k*l*m*n;  
  if (mult > highest)
    highest = mult; 
  System.out.println(highest);} 

  }}
```

Comment: And what are the right and wrong answers?

Comment: The wrong answer is 2091059712. I don't know the right answer.

Comment: How do you know that answer is wrong? Looks about the right length to me. Could you change all your `int` to `long` and try again?

Comment: It's a Project Euler problem, so I get an "x" if it's wrong. I tried to change the `int` to `long` but then `Character.getNumericValue` didn't work. Changing `int` to `long` just for `mult` and `highest` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine to me. It will give you a list of loop-size 988. Although you are putting a check to print value of highest product in each loop. I don't know what you mean by 'wrong' answer, i wonder if you even singled out the answer out of all the integers outputted by this function. It will be the last one by the way.

**Suggestions :** Store the temporary value of highest in some dummy integer and then print it out outside the loop.

There is a lot of scope to re-factor the code namely you could get rid of logic to get char array and you can do without the computational over head of multiplication of the integers when any of 13 digits is 0.

Comment: Not sure how it can be the last one as the string ends in 0.

Comment: At any moment highest will have the largest value of product of all the adjacent 13. I ran it locally, the output starts  
5000940
5000940
5000940 -> suppose 0 comes here; but code does if (mult > highest)
5000940 
...
...
...
it goes on such that the last one is the highest product of 13 adjacent numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have integer overflow; just the input numbers are far too large to fit in 31 bits. You need to use `BigInteger` instead.

Comment: I saved them as a String.

Comment: @microslayer And then put them in `int mult`.

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest a different approach using Java 8 (assuming you have it)? This might make things a bit easier to diagnose by getting rid of all the variables for holding the adjacent values.

```
List<Integer> digitList(String numberText) {
    return numberText.chars().map(c -> Character.digit(c, 10))
        .collect(Collectors.toList);
}

long highestAdjacentProduct(List<Integer> inputs) {
    int adjacentLength = 13;
    return IntStream.range(0, input.size() - adjacentLength)
        .mapToLong(i -> inputs.subList(i, i + adjacentLength)
            .stream().reduce(1, (n1, n2) -> n1 * n2)))
        .max();
}
```

This is used with `highestAdjacentProduct(digitList(inputString))`

The really nice thing about using streams like this is you can trivially add `peek` methods to print out intermediate values to ensure the calculations are working as you expect.